# Assistance with populating second <SELECT> with another <SELECT>

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, select

I have two SELECTS's.  Both are populated via mysql queries.  The second one needs to populate after the user makes a selection from the first `<SELECT>`.  Could anyone provide some direction on how best to accomplish this?

As a side note, I was able to accomplish this with AJAX by sending the value to a different page and causing the second `<SELECT>` to pop up, but the thing is I don't want it to pop up after an option is selected, I just want it to populate.  Perhaps I could alter my JS?

```
function showBus(selection_id)
{
    if (selection_id=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("Bus_Opt").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("Bus_Opt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/includes/adminPages/selectBusiness.inc.php?selection_id="+selection_id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Hello Community,

Thank you for your responses.  Some quick clarity, I basically just wanted both of my select boxes to appear at the same time even if the value of the first selection was "".  To accomplish this I added this function.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.Search.group.onchange()
};
```

document.your_form_name.your_select_id_name.onchange();

Comment: two comments: first of all I would use jQuery to handle the AJAX and DOM manipulation (i.e. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) this is better for cross-browser issue.
Second is not very clear what you want to obtain, maybe you can post also your markup as well as the PHP code.

Comment: `// code for IE6, IE5` >_<

Comment: Try to make it without AJAX first, with page reload. It would be great experience and understanding of the things.

Comment: My first select is populated via a mysql query.  I'm not sure how to use the first value in conjecture with ajax or js to populate the second select using the value from the first select in another mysql query.

Comment: I recommend **not** using AJAX if the data volume allows it, because repeated AJAX calls will cause unnecessary server load.  Just query your database once and store all necessary data in javascript as json, filter it, and populate your selects as needed.  Here is an approach I made for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43730295/2943403

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want second select to have these new options :

- `<option value='1'>First Value</option>`
- `<option value='2'>Second Value</option>`

And assuming your ajax's return value will be like this : `1@First Value|2@Second Value`

Change your code `document.getElementById("Bus_Opt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` By

```
var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
var options = a.split('|');
secondSelect = document.getElementById("id_of_second_select");
secondSelect.length = 0; // delete all options from second select
for (i=0; i < option.length; i++) {
    option = options[i].split('@');
    optionValue = option[0];
    optionText = option[1];
    secondSelect.options[secondSelect.options.length] = new Option(optionValue, optionText); // Add new option to second select
}
```

Comment: Just amend my code from `split('#')` to `split('@')`. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve what is shown in the "multi-selects" example here?:

http://simpleajax.googlecode.com/svn/docs/demos/simple_demos.html

It uses a library called [SimpleAjax](https://code.google.com/p/simpleajax/).

Answer (score 0):

The procedure can look like this: in your `selectBusiness.inc.php` script encode the values you're sending to browsers via [json-encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, e.g.

```
if (isset($_GET['selection_id'])) {
  // here read the values from your database according to $_GET['selection_id'] and put them to array
  $arr = array('option1' => 'value1', 'option2' => 'value2', 'option3' => 'value3');
  $str = json_encode($arr); // convert the array to string
  echo $str; // {"option1":"value1","option2":"value2","option3":"value3"}
  exit;
}
```

Now in javascript replace the

```js
document.getElementById("Bus_Opt").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

with the following code - it's using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); // convert the string back to object
console.log(obj); // 
var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
select2.length = 0;
for (var prop in obj) {
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option(prop, obj[prop]); // thanks to Erdo ;)
}
```